# Can you use a BTS7960 43A module as driver for a SPWM tranformer inverter

Tags: inverter, motordriver

I have a crazy idea, the [BTS7960 43A](https://www.handsontec.com/dataspecs/module/BTS7960%20Motor%20Driver.pdf) is a PWM motor driver module. It's maximum PWM frequency is 25Khz, and the build in MOSFETS have a quite low RDSon. So I was wondering if I can use this module as a driver for a transformer to make a 12/24Vdc to 120Vac inverter.
I want to use an Arduino together with this module to create a 25KH SPWM driver and use a standard transformer.
Let me know what you think of this idea and if this is possible or maybe why this is not a good idea. Has anyone seen this somewhere at the internet and can you give me some links.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a design service. I see no reason why the BTS device would not work driving a suitable transformer. It can’t tell the difference between a motor or transformer.